# If two pitchers pitch to the same batter, who is credited with the result of the at-bat?

Tags: baseball, mlb

Let us assume a hypothetical situation in an MLB game. A pitcher gets to a 2-2 count against the batter. Then the pitcher leaves the game - perhaps he sustains an injury while delivering a pitch, or is ejected by an umpire. In this case, the offense is allowed to substitute a new pitcher during the at-bat because the old pitcher left due to injury or ejection.

Which pitcher is credited with the result of the at-bat? Does it matter what the count is? Clearly if the batter hits a home run that is the responsibility of the new pitcher, but if the batter walks after going 3-0, would the new pitcher be credited with the walk after the first pitcher put him in the hole? Same with 0-2 and getting a strikeout.

What do the official MLB rules say about this? Section 5.10 covers substitutions including some pitcher-specific rules, but I cannot find anything about during an at-bat. Section 9.16 is pretty thorough with regards to swapping pitchers between batters in ERA calculations, but I have been unable to find anything about pitching statistics where a single batter faces two pitchers during a single at-bat.

Answer (score 7):

You needed to look in rule 9.16(h). Rule 9 deals with the official scoring of MLB games.  So based on the official rules at [mlb.com](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf):

> (h) A relief pitcher shall not be held accountable when the first
>    batter to whom he pitches reaches first base on four called balls if such batter has a decided advantage in the ball and strike count when pitchers are changed.
>
> > (1) If, when pitchers are changed, the count is
> >
> > > ```
> > >      2 balls, no strike,
> > >      2 balls, 1 strike,
> > >      3 balls, no strike, 
> > >      3 balls, 1 strike,
> > >      3 balls, 2 strikes,
> > > ```
> > >
> > > and the batter gets a base on balls, the official scorer shall charge that 
> > >             batter and the base on balls to the preceding pitcher, not to the relief 
> > >             pitcher.
> >
> > (2) Any other action by such batter, such as reaching base on a hit, an  error, a fielder’s choice, a force-out, or being
> >      touched by a pitched ball,  shall cause such a batter to be charged to
> >      the relief pitcher.   Rule 10.16(h) Comment: The provisions of Rule
> >      10.16(h)(2) shall not be  construed as affecting or conflicting with the provisions of Rule 10.16(g).
> >
> > (3) If, when pitchers are changed, the count is 2 balls, 2 strikes, 1
> >      ball, 2 strikes, 1 ball, 1 strike, 1 ball, no strike, no ball, 2
> >      strikes, no ball, 1 strike, the official scorer shall charge that
> >      batter and the actions of that batter  to the relief pitcher.